# Different results from similar floating-point functions

Tags: c++, floating-accuracy

so i have 2 functions that should do the same thing

```
float ver1(float a0, float a1) {
    float r0 = a0 - a1;
    if (abs(r0) > PI) {
        if (r0 > 0) {
            r0 -= PI2;
        } else {
            r0 += PI2;
            }
    }
    return r0;
}

float ver2(float a0, float a1) {
    float a2 = a1 - PI2;

    float r0 = a0 - a1;
    float r1 = a0 - a2;

    if (abs(r0) < abs(r1)) {
        return r0;
    }
    if (abs(r0) > abs(r1)) {
        return r1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

note: PI and PI2 are float constants of pi and 2*pi

The odd thing is that sometimes they produce different results, for example if you feed them 0.28605145 and 5.9433694 then the first one results in 0.62586737 and the second one in 0.62586755 and i cant figure out whats causing this.

If you manually calculate what the result should be you'll find that the second answer is correct. This function i use in a 2d physical sim and the really odd thing is that the first answer (the wrong one) works there while the second one (the right one) makes it act all kinds of crazy. Such a tiny difference from an unknown source and such a profound effect :|

At this point im switchign to matrices anyway but this odd situation got me curious, anybody know whats going on?

Comment: Floating-point isn't associative...

Comment: It'll be the peculiarities of floating point arithmetic and representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float` typically has a precision of about 24 bits, or about 7 decimal places.

You are subtracting two numbers of similar magnitude (`r0+PI2` in the first, `a1-PI2` in the second), and so are experiencing *loss of significance* - several of the most significant bits of the result are zero, so there are fewer bits left to represent the difference. That is why the answers match to only about 6 decimal places.

If you need more precision, then a `double` or a 32-bit or larger fixed-point representation might be more suitable than a `float`. There are also arbitrary-precision libraries available, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which can represent numbers with all the precision you need, although arithmetic will be significantly slower than with built-in types.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `fabs()` function instead of `abs()` because `abs()` only works with integer numbers. You'll get weird and wrong results when using `abs()` with floating points.

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: @tenfour of course it does. Both functions are bad because they use the wrong function for calculations. Using proper function would solve the problem.

Comment: calling `abs` with a float argument will indirectly call `fabs`. Changing the code to use `fabs` would not change anything. Furthermore even if this was true, when the question is "What's going on here?", answering with "Use `fabs`" is not helpful.

Comment: @tenfour you're wrong. abs(3.4f) equals to 3. The problem is with it, and what's going on is precisely getting 1 from abs(1.3) instead of 1.3. Here's the proof: http://ideone.com/D9uC2

Comment: Considering he doesn't return anything that's been through `abs`, I can't see how `abs` explains his answer.

Comment: Conditions do depend on `abs` results and could lead to wrong results (e.g. when a0 is 3.5f). It is not the only issue in the author's code, but Martin pointed to the other problem.

Comment: @UnknownGosu: You're assuming that the `abs` in the question is the C library version, not the C++ library version which is overloaded for all arithmetic types. But even if that were the case, it wouldn't be the cause of the reported discrepancy.

Answer (score -1):

Floating point numbers don't behave like mathematical real numbers. Every sum of 2 may result in a "error". So I wouldn't call the first correct and the second incorrect just because of one example. You need to be careful of every action you do with floats if you want to keep the error small.

The error is generally smaller if the abs of the numbers are in the same range.
And if the ranges are different the error tend to be bigger.

For example `10000000.0 + 0.1 - 10000000.0` is hardly ever `0.1`.

If you know the ranges of the input you can adjust the code to reduce errors.

Comment: pls add comment why the downvote so i can see whats the reason!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the first paragraph is rather vague and gives no advice beyond "be careful", and the second is only the case if the OP is only using C-library headers despite tagging the question C++.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Still wouldn't it be better to add a comment like you did, rather than a downvote. As the answer I gave was correct - perhaps not the most helpful. For sure it was easy to improve.

Comment: The problems associated with floating-point arithmetic aren't so much with addition, but with subtraction of values that are close together. That gets you the noise bits.

Comment: for me addition and subtraction of signed variables are pretty much the same. so every problem of subtraction is dual to one additon